# Rails assets:precompile - undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, asset-pipeline, each, precompile

Whenever I run `rake assets:precompile`, I get a strange error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass
```

I've tried stripping out CSS and JS code, but keep getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the version of Rails you are using?

Comment: Could you post the whole stack trace rake is giving you? This is likely an error with your application manifest (js or css)